# Question about a Topological Property

Tags: real-analysis

My definition of a topological property of the real numbers system is: "A property of a subset of the real number's that does not change upon the application of a homeomorphism to that set."

I understand the concept behind the definition but I'm confused on how to use it to answer this question.

Question: "Is the property that a set contains all the real numbers a topological property? Prove your result"

Any hints to help me get in the right direction?

Comment: Consider the inverse of a certain trig. function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a subset $A$ of the real numbers containing all the real numbers. (How many are there?) Now apply a homeomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to $A$. Does $\varphi(A)$ still contain all real numbers?